# sbt-jacoco@3.5.0 Java 17 and sbt 1.9.8 and Scala 2.13 : report coverage is zero for all categories

Tags: sbt, jacoco, sbt-plugin

```
[info] Lines: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 1000 missed, OK                                                                                                                            
[info] Instructions: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 1000 missed, OK                                                                                                                                                      
[info] Branches: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 1000 missed, OK                                                                                                                                                            
[info] Methods: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 1000 missed, OK                                                                                                                                                              
[info] Complexity: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 1000 missed, OK                                                                                                                                                          
[info] Class: 0% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 1000 missed, OK
```

unit tests were already written since system was with java 11, it had no issue. Reports shows zero after updated to java 17

```
[info] Lines: 50% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 200 missed, OK                                                                                                                            
[info] Instructions: 50% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 200 missed, OK                                                                                                                                                      
[info] Branches: 50% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 200 missed, OK                                                                                                                                                            
[info] Methods: 50% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 200 missed, OK                                                                                                                                                              
[info] Complexity: 50% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 200 missed, OK                                                                                                                                                          
[info] Class: 50% (>= required 0.0%) covered, 1000 of 200 missed, OK
```

this should be the results